# In case of success login via IMAP, an email server replies without "OK" and tag

Tags: email, imap

When I'm doing IMAP authentication of one the public email servers and login is successful I believe, it replies like this:

```
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 ID XLIST UIDPLUS UNSELECT MOVE LIST-STATUS
```

There's no `OK` as you can see, neither a `TAG` value. However, according to this
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.2.3 they should be included always.

Why?

In case of unsuccesful login, it replies like this:

```
TAG_2 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed
```

which makes sense.

Comment: Can you share what is the public server?

Comment: @Anthon,  mail.ru